# Make electron-packager use local files, vs downloading from internet

Tags: electron

When I run:

`electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune`

It downloads "electron-v1.3.4-linux-x64.zip" (42MB)

I'd like it to look for that file somewhere locally, like /home/vagrant/packages/electron-v1.3.4-linux-x64.zip

How can I do that?

Also, I'm aware that electron-download caches, but I'm asking for a CI server that doesn't persist the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I just need to copy the file into /root/.electron as a build step and the CI step that runs electron-package will use that. root being the user the CI runs as.